# Can An EditText be added to a custom spinner?

Tags: android, filter, spinner

As the title says, can this be done i.e custom spinner having the first row as an EditText that can filter the ArrayAdapter of that spinner (same as a search in a ListView)?

Comment: why you use spinner , please use AutoCompleteText View , This must be helpful for your situation

Comment: thank you for your response, but i am using a spinner because the user should have the options to see what he can select and the ability to filter the list

Comment: i am just curious to see if its possible because i cant see how it would work

Comment: With Autocomplete text you also have this option , like if you type a , it display all possible results containing a , then user can select any one from them , This is more appropriate than spinner because in case if you have 10K results then this provide faster results .